# @PreUpdate doesn't return correct exception message

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink, glassfish-3

To validate my entity beans I have created this validation method inside my bean

```
@PrePersist
@PreUpdate
public void validate(){
    if (startTime.after(stopTime)) throw new ValidationException("Wrong order");
}
```

The ValidationException looks like this:

```
@ApplicationException(rollback = true)
public class ValidationException extends RuntimeException {


public ValidationException(String message) {
    super(message);
}
}
```

If I try to create a bean with

```
try {
        timeframefacade.create(timeframe);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
```

e.getMessage() returns "Wrong order", which is correct

```
try {
        timeframefacade.edit(timeframe);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
```

it returns "Transaction aborted" which is an EJBException. How do I get the same result as above and avoid all the logging, which also occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call flush within your edit method to force the preupdate. Otherwise it occurs when the transaction is completing and the container must throw a transaction exception instead.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. Hopefully the flush operation won't have any negative impact to the rest of thje edits...

Comment: Just one more thing, if you still read: After the creation command (persist) the logger stays quite, if an exception is being catched, after the edit command however (merge,flush), the whole printstack written to the console. Do you know how to avoid this?